# What is wrong with my HTML?

Tags: html, css

When I add something to my css file to test, nothing happens on the webpage.

Random text so that I can post this without it asking for more details.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Basket Gifts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<img src="http://www.displaybanner.com/images/sample_banner.jpg"   alt="Banner">

        </div> <!--ends the header-->

        <div id="main">
            <p>Mum & Baby girl gifts<br>
            <p>Mum & Baby boy gifts<br>
            <p>Nail & Beauty products<br>
            <p>Food Hamper<br>
            <p>Chocolate Hamper<br>
            <p>Fruit Basket<br>
            <P>Cheese & Biscuits Hamper<br>

            <br><br>
            <h3>Select your price range</h3>
            <form>
                <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value">$30-40</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value">$40-50</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value">$50-60</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value">$60-70</input><br>
                    <br><br>
                <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name"><br>
                <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Address"><br>
                <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Phone Number"><br>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br>
                <input type="text" name="confirm email" placeholder="Confirm Email">
            </form>
        </div> <!--Ends the main content area-->

        <div id="footer">
        <p>Your Receipt and order confirmation will be sent to your email soon, A confirmation of delivery will be sent three days before the date required.<br> Please not all baskets will be posted. <br>No collections are appplicable.<br>
        </div> <!--ends the footer-->
    </div> <!--ends the container-->
</body>
```

What is wrong with this? my css doesnt link to my html file.

style.css:

```
#container {
background-color: red;
}

#header {
background-color: red;
}

p {
font-family: calibri;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your style.css file in the css subdirectory?

Comment: Is your style.css file in the css folder. First check it.

Comment: You should also not use a closing input tag. Instead, if you want text to be associated with your input element use a label.

Comment: yes, it is in the css folder.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have several wrong in your html code, I added fixed html and css for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Basket Gifts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header" >
            <h1>Basket Gifts</h1>
            <p>Would you like baskets made and delivered anywhere in New Zealand? Click on the link below to choose what types of basket you want,<br> choose the price range and the the delivery address, and the date required. once all the contact details and the direct credit payment is confirmed,<br> an email will be sent to you confirming delivery, and the number of the track and trace parcel Please allow for two weeks before the requested date.</p>
        </div> <!--ends the header-->

        <div id="main" >

            <p>Mum & Baby girl gifts</p>
            <p>Mum & Baby boy gifts</p>
            <p>Nail & Beauty products</p>
            <p>Food Hamper</p>
            <p>Chocolate Hamper</p>
            <p>Fruit Basket</p>
            <P>Cheese & Biscuits Hamper</p>

        <br><br>
        <h3>Select your price range</h3>
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value" />$30-40<br>
            <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value" />$40-50<br>
            <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value" />$40-50<br>
            <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value" />$60-70<br>
                <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" /><br>
            <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Address" /><br>
            <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Phone Number" /><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" /><br>
            <input type="text" name="confirm email" placeholder="Confirm Email" />
        </form>

        </div> <!--Ends the main content area-->

        <div id="footer" >
            <p>Your Receipt and order confirmation will be sent to your email soon, A confirmation of delivery will be sent three days before the date required.<br> Please not all baskets will be posted. <br>No collections are appplicable.</p>
        </div> <!--ends the footer-->
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS

```
#container {
    background-color: red;
}

#header {
    background-color: red;
}

p {
    font-family: calibri;
}

#main, #footer, #container, #header {
    text-align: center
}
```

Comment: When donw vote an answer please considerate put comment about your desition of down vote it

Comment: Sorry @GrahamMackintosh my comment it's not for you. :)

Answer (score -1):

I did run your code, It works fine.

If even without correct your code, it was also works fine.. I mean your styles are applied in `html` file.

Here is [Image](http://s4.postimg.org/7ntnnbugd/untitled.jpg) when run your code(without correct your code)

Even though, you missed lots of close tags,

Here is corrected code,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Basket Gifts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<img src="http://www.displaybanner.com/images/sample_banner.jpg"   alt="Banner">

        </div> <!--ends the header-->

        <div id="main">
            <p>Mum & Baby girl gifts</p><br>
            <p>Mum & Baby boy gifts</p><br>
            <p>Nail & Beauty products</p><br>
            <p>Food Hamper</p><br>
            <p>Chocolate Hamper</p><br>
            <p>Fruit Basket</p><br>
            <P>Cheese & Biscuits Hamper</p><br>

            <br><br>
            <h3>Select your price range</h3>
            <form>
                <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value">$30-40</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value">$40-50</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value">$50-60</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="hi" value="value">$60-70</input><br>
                    <br><br>
                <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name"><br>
                <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Address"><br>
                <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Phone Number"><br>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br>
                <input type="text" name="confirm email" placeholder="Confirm Email">
            </form>
        </div> <!--Ends the main content area-->

        <div id="footer">
        <p>
        Your Receipt and order confirmation will be sent to your email soon, A confirmation of delivery will be sent three days before the date required.<br> Please not all baskets will be posted. <br>No collections are appplicable.<br>
        </p>
        </div> <!--ends the footer-->
    </div> <!--ends the container-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay @GrahamMackintosh. thanks... did you got solution?

Comment: yeah, my question got answered... why is someone coming into my thread and downvoting everything?